Find the last match
I need your help in finding the LAST match. Unfortunately, my pattern does not work as I need. I need to find the last match of a set of characters consisting of two characters "{{", one or more numbers, may be letters (but may not be) and two characters "}}". + these characters must be underlined and bold. For exxcample: {{000015}} or {{000026WRR}}. However, my version of the pattern necessarily searches for letters. The search also loops.
    myDocument.Range.Find.ClearFormatting
        
    With myDocument.Range
        With .Find

            .Text = "\{{2}[0-9]{1,}[A-z]*\}{2}"

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = True
                
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
                
            .Execute
        End With

        Do While .Find.Found
      
            myStr = .Text
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Find.Execute
        Loop
   End With
        
   MsgBox myStr


The asterisk (*) in Word represents 0 or more characters but does not function as a repetition operator like it does in regular expressions.

Try:
.Text = "\{\{[0-9A-Z]@\}\}"


To get the last match in the document change .Forward = True to .Forward = False
This will start the find from the end of the document so the first match will be the last.

Thank you, Timothy. But the problem with patterns is not solved.
